# ng2-charts - Highlighting a series when hovering over the corresponding legend label

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using the ng2-charts library in my Angular application to display charts. I would like to implement a feature where, when hovering over the corresponding legend label of a series, that series gets highlighted in the chart.

How can I achieve this behavior with ng2-charts? Is there a way to modify the styling of the series when the mouse hovers over the associated legend label?

I have already gone through the documentation of ng2-charts but couldn't find specific information about this. Any code snippet examples or detailed guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I am using chart.js version 4.2.1 and ng2-charts version 4.1.1.

Here's my code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, ChartData, ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { ListService } from '../../services/component-services/list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss'],
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscriptions = [];

  @Input()
  guiConfig;

  @Input()
  minValue;

  @Input()
  maxValue;

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((sub) => {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'>;
  constructor(private listService: ListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    let sub = this.listService.getBehaviorSubject(this.guiConfig['dataId']).subscribe((data) => {
      let barChartDataMap: Map<JSON, object[]> = new Map<JSON, object[]>();
      let labels = [];
      let values = [];
      let captions: JSON[] = [];
      if (data !== undefined && data.length !== 0) {
        for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
          const element = data[index];
          if (!labels.includes(element['xValue'])) {
            labels.push(element['xValue']);
          }
          values.push(element['yValue']);
          let caption = element['caption'];
          let jsonObj = {};
          jsonObj['caption'] = caption;
          jsonObj['color'] = element['color'];
          let extistsKey = captions.find((caption) => {
            return JSON.stringify(caption) == JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
          });
          if (!extistsKey) {
            captions.push(<JSON>jsonObj);
          }
        }

        let datasets = [];

        for (let index = 0; index < captions.length; index++) {
          const caption = captions[index];
          let dataArray = [];
          for (let innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < data.length; innerIndex++) {
            const dataPoint = data[innerIndex];
            if (dataPoint['caption'] == caption['caption']) {
              dataArray.push(dataPoint['yValue']);
            }
          }
          barChartDataMap.set(caption, dataArray);
        }
        for (let el of barChartDataMap.keys()) {
          let data = barChartDataMap.get(el);
          let dataset = {};
          dataset['data'] = data;
          dataset['label'] = el['caption'];
          dataset['barThickness'] = 20;
          dataset['borderRadius'] = 5;
          //Adds space between bars
          dataset['borderColor'] = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
          dataset['borderWidth'] = 2;
          dataset['backgroundColor'] = el['color'];
          datasets.push(dataset);
        }

        let barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
          datasets: datasets,
          labels: labels
        }
        this.barChartData = barChartData;
      }
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(sub);
  }

  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: false,
    onHover: // ...

  }

  @ViewChild('canvas')
  canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  public getCanvas(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvas.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need the [`options.plugins.legend.onHover`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options) callback function to capture the event when the legend has hovered.
2. To highlight the bar elements, you need to call the `setActiveElements` method and provide items of `ActivePoints[]`. The key point is the `ActivePoints` items must with the `datasetIndex` which is the currently selected legend item index (`legendItem.datasetIndex`) and `index` for each item index in the dataset. Reference: [Programmatic Event Triggers](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/programmatic-events.html)

```
import { Chart, ChartConfiguration, LegendItem } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) baseChart!: BaseChartDirective;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.barChartOptions = {
    ...this.barChartOptions,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        onHover: (evt, legendItem: LegendItem) => {
          this.baseChart?.chart?.setActiveElements(
            this.baseChart!.chart!.getDatasetMeta(
              legendItem.datasetIndex!
            ).data!.map((x, i) => ({
              datasetIndex: legendItem.datasetIndex!,
              index: i,
            }))
          );

          this.baseChart.update();
        },
      },
    },
  };
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4zfcwv-fcu5ix?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But i have a question, why doesnt this method work with a doughnutchart?

Comment: Didn't try this *config* on doughnut chart before. Maybe I need to take some time to have a look. In case, you may create a new question regarding this and let see Stack Overflow-ers have any idea/solution. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much anyways!